# casting in implementing gflist_vt_mergesort$cmp

Tags: ats

In [gflist_vt.sats](https://github.com/githwxi/ATS-Postiats/blob/master/libats/SATS/gflist_vt.sats), the signature of `gflist_vt_mergesort$cmp` implies that the order used for sorting must be the same as that of stamp. I understand that if such comparing function is given, the soundness of the function is ensured.

In [this example](https://github.com/githwxi/ATS-Postiats/blob/master/doc/EXAMPLE/ATSLIB/libats_gflist.dats), `gflist_vt_mergesort$cmp` seems to be implemented using unsafe casting.

- Is it safe to do that? (i.e. Doesn't that cause any problem? e.g. What if the list is sorted multiple times with different ordering?)
- Is there any other (safer) way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unsafe casting is inherently *unsafe*.

Unsafe casting can be removed. In order to do so, you need to implement the abstract type `stamped_vt0ype` (which is given the alias `stamped_vt`). For instance, to sort an integer list in descending order, you could do something as follows:

```
local

assume stamped_vt0ype(_, i) = int(~i)

in (* in-of-local *)

implement
{a}
gflist_vt_mergesort$cmp(x, y) = g1int_sgn(y - x)

end // end of [local]
```

However, doing something like this does not seem to offer much in terms of practical programming.